# Linux Stealth Process

Tags: linux, centos, process, malware, stealth

I have a process named "stealth" that has infected my server (slamming my CPU) and I can't figure out where it is to remove it for good. Everytime I kill the process it somehow starts itself again...

`ps -ef | grep stealth` gives me this:

[image: ps showing stealth process]

But I have no idea where ./stealth would be since it's a relative path?

Also when I try using `locate` or `find`, I get nothing.

Any ideas how I can find and remove this process?

Comment: I wouldn't settle for just removing the process...

Comment: What you mean a rebuild? I'm thinking that's the way I'll go.

Comment: It's running under apache's id. Shutdown the apache service and then kill the process to see if apache was the infected host process.

Comment: Running under the Apache user, so that's a good bet on where it came from.

Comment: If you kill it now, you won’t be able to figure out what’s going on. At least not until the intruder starts it up again at 4:00AM a week from now. At least that’s been my experience with this sort of thing.

Comment: do a `find /tmp | grep -i stealth`, people with similar infections found the executables and hackers break-in tools in /tmp.

Comment: [Nuke from orbit - it's the only way to be sure](http://nukeitfromorbit.com/)

Comment: Do crackware authors think that naming an executable "stealth" will make it invisible to admins? :)

Comment: @Tim - That turned it up. See this: http://cl.ly/2Y0I1F131x3x1E0g1t3w. Tricky little thing.

Comment: @MichaelKropat You're right. That's why I left it running for now.

Comment: Great! I would go ahead and nuke that folder `.shy`

Comment: I'd go with the nuke-and-rebuild approach, but definitely do what you can to investigate, first (disconnected from the network, if you can).  See [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency).

Comment: @ShaneMadden Exactly. I had an old version of PHPMyAdmin laying stagnant on the server. (I know, stupid me). I think it was uploaded through that.

Comment: @janneb there is at least 1 admin that it would work on.

Comment: Out of interest, before you nuke it from orbit, do strace -p 11377 and pastebin the output for us all to see.

Comment: @TomO'Connor I tried, but I don't have `strace` installed on my server and couldn't get `yum` to run with that process running.

Comment: Boo.  What a shame.

Comment: It's probably a simple IRC client/bot joined to a server/channel owned by the intruder (port 6667 is a default IRC port and IRC bots are a very popular means of remote control.) If you can snoop the connection you might learn something interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I’m not mistaken, `ls -l /proc/11377/exe` will tell you where the file is located. Removing it might be a whole other matter though.

Comment: That's excellent. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Your computer is compromised. If possible replace the server with an clean one or reinstall it. You should not trust it anymore.

Comment: That's the plan.

Answer (score 1):

1. before running `locate`, run `updatedb` to make sure the "locate" database is current
2. the fact that the process respawns means it is under the supervision of another process (init, daemontools, cron, etc). Look at the process parent-id to find out which process is launching it. This program will need to be examined to figure out what relationship it has to the stealth program
3. examine the proc entry for the process id, look at `/proc/[pid]/cwd` this gives you the "current working directory" which will tell you where `./stealth` is
4. `kill -SIGSTOP [pid]` will stop (suspend) the process without killing it, letting you examine it without worrying about it doing anything further.